# Google Sheets AppsScript - Send an email when 1 cell changes to False

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've found a few AppsScript examples but nothing that matches what I am trying to do.

I have a google sheet and I want to recieve an email if 1 particular cell value changes from TRUE to FALSE. This cell has an IF function and will change based on other events. I just want an email if the value changes to false.

I know I need to create a function in AppsScript and a trigger event but I just cant seem to get the code correct.

The tab in the sheet is **HealthMon** and the Cell that I am looking at is **F2**. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the following script:

```
function emailSender(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HealthMon');
  var r = ss.getRange("F2");
  if(r.getValue()==true)
  {
    GmailApp.sendEmail("user@domain.com", "Test subject", "This is a test message");
// Change the email address to the desired one
  }
}
```

Make sure to [add the following trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

[image]

#### References:

- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [GmailApp: sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)

Comment: this worked perfect. How would I send to multiple emails?

Comment: @snowblind You can just add more email addresses separated by a comma like `"user@domain.com, user2@domain.com, user3@domain.com"`... etc.